# Send HTTP Request from frontend (client-side) in PHP

Tags: php

This script requests the target server from server ip. The problem is too many request from the same server IP will lead to ban. So i want this script to request target server from client-side IP.

Is it possible? or should I implement proxy in this script?

Comment: Then you will have to implement the same code in Javascript, if you want to send the request from the client.

Comment: You can write a client side version with JS, but your source might not allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: @deceze so its not possible to do in PHP? Sorry, i dont have knowledge in coding.

Comment: You can't run PHP client-side. Together with your question from yesterday I really wonder what bot you're working on ... and all this without knowledge in coding.

Comment: PHP can only send requests from the server it runs on. PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: @deceze got it! so is it recommended to implement proxy in this php script or should i go with javascript?

Comment: @digijay haha!  previous post is totally different. i hired few devs from upwork. just posting on stackoverflow to get some opinons!

Answer (score 1):

You can make HTTP requests on behalf of the client if:

1. You do this in javascript
2. The code is running in the browser, not the server
3. The host you are trying to connect to lets you (through CORS headers)

aside: I wouldn't attempt to write a HTTP client from scratch